# Map becomes null

Tags: java, dictionary, null

I am using a Map, cloning it and working with the clone. After the clone has been worked with, the original Map is modified and I don't understand why.

```
System.out.println("foo = " + GeneMap.get("foo"));
Map<String,Integer> GeneMapClone = GeneMap;
for(int i = 0; i<BestArray.length; i++) {
    for(Map.Entry<String,Integer>entry:GeneMapClone.entrySet()){
        if(BestArray[i] == entry.getValue()) {
            GeneArray[i] = entry.getKey();
            GeneMapClone.remove(entry.getKey());
            break;
        }
    }
}
System.out.println("foo = " + GeneMap.get("foo"));
```

This will print out the following:

```
foo = 6
foo = null
```

By modifying GeneMapClone, am I also modifying GeneMap since it is pointing to it? How can I avoid this?

Comment: Assignment doesn't make clones.

Answer (score 5):

To make clone you have to use `HashMap` constructor [HashMap(Map m)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#HashMap(java.util.Map)) like

```
 Map<String,Integer> GeneMapClone = new HashMap<>(GeneMap);
```

because currently `GeneMap` and `GeneMapClone` are both pointing to same object in heap memory

Comment: Glad to help, happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

In your code

> Map GeneMapClone = GeneMap;

You are pointing GeneMapClone to original object that is GeneMap not the clone object

 If both are pointing to same object changing one will also change the other

Answer (score 1):

You're not actually making a clone of the map.  You're just pointing a new variable to the existing single map object.

See the comments in the below code.

```
    // Making variables for the code to compile
    Integer [] BestArray = new Integer[100];
    String[] GeneArray = new String[100];
    Map<String, Integer> GeneMap = new HashMap<>();

    System.out.println("foo = " + GeneMap.get("foo"));

    // The below line doesn't clone `GeneMap`
    // It creates a new variable named `GeneMapClone` which points to the one map copy which is 'GeneMap'
    // So after the below line, there's still just 1 map in memory, pointed at by 2 differently-named variables
    Map<String,Integer> GeneMapClone = GeneMap;
    for(int i = 0; i<BestArray.length; i++) {
        for(Map.Entry<String,Integer>entry:GeneMapClone.entrySet()){
            if(BestArray[i] == entry.getValue()) {
                GeneArray[i] = entry.getKey();
                GeneMapClone.remove(entry.getKey());
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("foo = " + GeneMap.get("foo"));
```

Also, FWIW, the typical convention is to camel-case variable names in Java. That led to some confusion reading the post.